# Logo in Navigation Bar Swift not showing

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add a logo to my page's navigation bar, however it doesn't appear when I added this code to my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "Dog_Log_Icon_H_W")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Does anybody know why this might not be working? I checked that the image name is correct. This is my storyboard if it helps:

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Is your image format is .png or .jpg?

Comment: format is png, why?

Comment: The reason is that named property of UIImage is take the whole name if the format is other than .png.

Answer (score 1):

So it worked when I made an outlet,

`@IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!`

then put the following code in my `viewDidAppear`:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "Dog_Log_Icon_4"){
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
navItem.titleView = imageView
```

not sure why I had to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the frame of the image view. I have set frame of the image view and it works fine.

```
  if let logo = UIImage(named: "download"){
            let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
            self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

        }else{
            print("Image not found...")
        }
```

Comment: Still not showing, here is a picture of my UI at runtime: http://imgur.com/a/MuO72

Comment: I think your image not available. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you forgot set the position for the `imageView`.
You can change your code like this:

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "Dog_Log_Icon_H_W")
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
imageView.image = logo
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Comment: Still not showing, here is a picture of my UI at runtime: http://imgur.com/a/MuO72